# bpf_skb_cgroup_id works perfectly for egress. How to get the cgroup id for ingress traffic for tc ingress ebpf hook

Tags: linux-kernel, ebpf, bpf

I am attaching the below program in the tc ingress as well as egress of veth host-side. I am able to get the proper cgroup id for ingress (egress from container) and the reverse path cgroup id is empty. How to get the cgroup id for ingress (veth host-side) tc hook?

```
SEC("simple")
int handle_ingress(struct __sk_buff *skb)
{

    bpf_printk("tc: bpf_skb_cgroup_id:ox%llx", bpf_skb_cgroup_id(skb));
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That information is not available on ingress. From [the BPF helpers documentation](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/bpf-helpers.7.html):

> This helper can be used on TC egress path, but not on ingress, and is available only if the kernel compiled with the `CONFIG_SOCK_CGROUP_DATA` configuration option.